# Use relative url in QML Webview

Tags: qt, url, webview, qml, relative-path

I'm trying to get QML (main.qml) to load a local HTML file index.html using 
        `url: "file:///../../htmlfiles/index.html"`
but it doesn't work.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up passing `qApp->applicationDirPath()` from c++ to QML using `setContextProperty()` and used `url: "file:///" + applicationDirPath + "/htmlfiles/index.html"` to fix the issue.

Comment: `engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("workingDirectory", QUrl::fromLocalFile(app.applicationDirPath()));` in Qt 5.

Answer (score 3):

```
WebView {
        url: Qt.resolvedUrl( "html/index.html" )
        x: 0
        y: 0
        smooth: false
        anchors {
            top: window.top
            bottom: window.bottom
            left: window.left
            right: window.right
        }
    }
```

This works for me!

Answer (score 2):

Try without `file:///`:

```
WebView {
    url: "../../htmlfiles/index.html"
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: I copied the htmlfiles directory using DEPLOYMENT in .pro, and for some reason this solution doesn't work (maybe I'm missing something). My QML is bundled using .qrc file and the HTML file is copied using the above method. Is that the problem?

Comment: @pshah: If the QML file is compiled into the program binary and the HTML file is located outside the binary, it cannot be referenced by a relative path, because the files are in two different "file systems".

Answer (score 1):

There is simpler way to do that:

```
WebView {
        id: translationsList
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "qrc:/about.html"
        }
```

Comment: As Radon suggested in the comments section, I think this won't work. "@pshah: If the QML file is compiled into the program binary and the HTML file is located outside the binary, it cannot be referenced by a relative path, because the files are in two different "file systems".

Answer (score 0):

try :
       filename="/etc/issue";
       url =  Qt.resolvedUrl( filename );